# ASP.NET MVC 5, Storing list values in Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, session

I am trying to store list of products in List<> which I have stored in session, but when I add second product it only shows first in my View page.
..............

```
List<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems = new List<ShoppingCartItem>
        {
            new ShoppingCartItem() {Product = product.Name, Attributes = atts, Options = opts, Price = producttotalprice, Quantity = 1}
        };

        if (Session["Cart"] == null)
        {
            Session["Cart"] = ShoppingCartItems;
        }

        return View(Session["Cart"]);

    }
```

Anybody can help me please to retrieve all products I have stored.

Comment: Where is you code for adding the _second product_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a `new List<ShoppingCartItem>` *every time* and only ever putting one element in that list.  It *sounds like* you want to first check if there's *already* a list in the session.  And, if so, add the new element to *that* list.  Something like this:

```
List<ShoppingCartItem> shoppingCartItems;
if (Session["Cart"] != null)
{
    shoppingCartItems = (List<ShoppingCartItem>)Session["Cart"];
}
else
{
    shoppingCartItems = new List<ShoppingCartItem>();
}

shoppingCartItems.Add(new ShoppingCartItem() {Product = product.Name, Attributes = atts, Options = opts, Price = producttotalprice, Quantity = 1});
Session["Cart"] = shoppingCartItems;

return View(shoppingCartItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is the "add" code, you're not actually amending the list. You're declaring an entirely new ShoppingCartItems list which contains the new product.

It works for the first product because this returns true:

```
if (Session["Cart"] == null)
```

The second time around this is false, and nothing happens. What you want to do is:

1) Retrieve the session cart which is a 'List' (if it is null, then initialise a new one.

2) Create a new ShoppingCartItem from the product which has been passed to the controller. Add that product to the cart.